# After updating the selenium jar and IE driver executable files. My script is running very slow

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-iedriver

It is finding the element very fast but taking so much time to perform the actions like click or sendkeys. Currently updated files are Selenium Jar-3.7.1 and IEDriverExecutable-3.8.0

Answer (score 0):

It is tough to answer/recommend anything with the information provided within the question currently. But using `IEDriverExecutable-3.8.0` along with `Selenium Jar-3.7.1` may be a potential issue.

- The [*SeleniumHQ Download*](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/) page says the following : *The Internet Explorer Driver Server is required if you want to make use of the latest and greatest features of the WebDriver InternetExplorerDriver. Please make sure that this is available on your $PATH (or %PATH% on Windows) in order for the IE Driver to work as expected.*
- As per best practices, if you are using *Selenium v3.7.x.y* binaries try to use *IEDriverServer v3.7.x.y* binaries along with it.
- Ensure that you have configured the mandatory settings as per [**`InternetExplorerDriver`**](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#required-configuration) page.
- Finally it is worth to mention that your test execution speed will be slower while using the *IEDriverServer 64-bit version* with respect to test execution speed using *IEDriverServer 32-bit version* because of [*IE driver server 64 bit is typing very slowly using Sendkeys*](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/1464) and [*IE x64 slow typing*](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/5116)